# php code to load wp post unsing a unique field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to php and Wordpress.  I am trying to get a php code snippet working to display a wordpress post based on a unique field. I have posts that have a field named "unique_key". The "unique_key" field has text values representing dates in the format "20161126", "20161127", "20161128", etc, each day I need the php to load the post based on the unique_key for the current date and then display the post. Below is my code that does not work.
Any help would be appreciated as why this code is broken.

```
$sDate = idate('Y');
$sDate .= idate('m');
$sDate .= idate('d');
$intDate = (int)$sDate;
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_key' => 'unique_key',
  'meta_value' => '{$intDate}'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $the_query->have_posts() ):
while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
echo "<h1><u><a href='{the_permalink()}'>{the_title()}</a></u></h1>";
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Just how doesn't it work? Is there an error? Does something not display?

Comment: `'{$intDate}'` should just be `$intDate` -- no need for quotes or brackets

Answer (score 0):

To get the post according to post meta you need pass meta query inside the `meta_query` array.

```
$sDate = idate('Y');
$sDate .= idate('m');
$sDate .= idate('d');
$intDate = (int)$sDate;
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_query' => array(
      array(
            'meta_key' => 'unique_key',
            'meta_value' => '{$intDate}'
      )
  )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $the_query->have_posts() ):
while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
echo "<h1><u><a href='{the_permalink()}'>{the_title()}</a></u></h1>";
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Try this code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It turn out the unique_key is in different MySql Database. I will post wjat ended up working below.

Answer (score 0):

A little more background might help if someone has this same issue. We used a WordPress plugin named "WP All Import" to import 5000+ jokes into a WordPress project for a joke a day. We used a "unique_key" field as a text string formatted like "20161126", "20161127","20161128", etc. The goal was to display the joke that has the current date. When I looked at the MySql databases, the "unique_key" is in a different database from the joke posts. I used a WordPress plugin named "Post Snippets". This plugin allows PHP code to be added to the WordPress page as a "[Short-Code]". What I found worked was to look up the unique_key value in one of "post" database using a MySql "Select: statement, load the unique record, then display the post using WordPress functions. The code below works perfectly.

```
//Define Login Info
$servername = "YOUR_SERVER";
$username = "YOUR_USERNAME";
$password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
$dbname = "YOUR_DB_NAME";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
// Get Unique_key for today's date Adjusted for GMT
//See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n
$sUID = (string)date_i18n('Ymd');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `DB_WHERE_UNIQUE_KEY_EXISTS_posts` WHERE `unique_key`= {$sUID}";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sID = $row["post_id"]; // Get Post ID
        $sTitle = get_the_title($sID);
        $sLink = get_permalink($sID);
        $sPost = get_post($sID);

        echo "<h1><u><a href='{$sLink}'>{$sTitle}</a></u></h1>";
     // Uncomment line below if you want full post shown
     // $text=apply_filters( 'the_content', $sPost->post_content); 

        $excerpt = apply_filters('get_the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $sPost->ID));
//Code to make Excerpt if no excerpt exists
       if ( $excerpt == '' ) {
          $excerpt = wp_trim_words( $sPost->post_content, 55 );
       }
       echo "<b>" . $excerpt . "</b>";
       //Use line below if you want full post
       //echo "<b>" . apply_filters( 'the_content', $sPost->post_content) . "</b>";

       echo "<a href='{$sLink}'></br><b>read more</b></a>";
    }
}
else {
  echo "<h2>No Joke Today, Sorry! Check Back Tomorrow...</h2>";
}

$conn->close();
```